# Trying to create a marquee in CSS3

Tags: html, css, marquee, css-animations

i'm trying to create a marquee in full CSS3, but it doesn't move like it should

HTML:

```
<div id="marquee">
    <ul class="li_patr">
        <li class="unstiled_li"><img id="element" src="img/thumb1.png"></li>
        <li class="unstiled_li"><img id="element" src="img/thumb2.png"></li>
        <li class="unstiled_li"><img id="element" src="img/thumb3.png"></li>
        <li class="unstiled_li"><img id="element" src="img/thumb4.png"></li>
        <li class="unstiled_li"><img id="element" src="img/thumb5.png"></li>
        <li class="unstiled_li"><img id="element" src="img/thumb6.png"></li>
        <li class="unstiled_li"><img id="element" src="img/thumb7.png"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#marquee{
width: 960px;
height: 160px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.li_patr{
width: 1500px;
}
.unstiled_li{
list-style: none;
margin-top: 0;
-webkit-animation: marquee 25s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

Animation in css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
0% { left: 0; }
100% { left: -100%; }
}
@-moz-keyframes marquee {
0% { left: 0; }
100% { left: -100%; }
}
@-ms-keyframes marquee {
0% { left: 0; }
100% { left: -100%; }
}
@-o-keyframes marquee {
0% { left: 0; }
100% { left: -100%; }
}
@keyframes marquee {
0% { left: 0; }
100% { left: -100%; }
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle where i replace some images: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZaGk/

Comment: You forgot to position `.unstiled_li` - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZaGk/2/)

Comment: I added the position relative thanks!, but i want that when the <ul> finish moving start another <ul> right behind it to make an efect that is infinite, do you understand me? @Adrift

Comment: @GermanKatz You'd have to use a different animation for each element then. It'd be easier to just use a javascript version

Comment: Make sure get rid of all those duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a solution like this:
http://jonmifsud.com/open-source/jquery/jquery-webticker/

It offers an infinite webticker.